# for classicthesis: mirroring format of chapter numbers and graffito

Tags: classicthesis

With my current classicthesis doc used in Lyx, the default format is for odd numbered pages to have a wide margin on the right.
I would like odd pages to have a large margin on the left (for binding)
I have changed this using the following in the preamble:

```
% REVERSE MARGINS  
\let\tmp\oddsidemargin
\let\oddsidemargin\evensidemargin
\let\evensidemargin\tmp
\reversemarginpar
```

I have also set chapters to start on odd pages using the option:

```
openright
```

This seems to work alright but I would like the fancy chapter numbers and graffito comments to be on the outside margin rather than the inside margin of the pages.
How do I move these?

Comment: Wrong approach, IMO. If you're using [this template](https://code.google.com/p/classicthesis/downloads/list), then to account for the binding you want to set the `BCOR` (binding correction) parameter for the document class. The default value is 5mm, meaning that 5mm is added to the inner edge, in addition to the margin. If you fear that more is lost in the binding, increase that value in Document --> Settings --> Document Class.

Comment: BCOR helps with getting the margins correct but does not solve the issue of the graffito comments and chapter numbers appearing on the wrong side of the page. I would like them on the outer part of the page rather than the inner.

Comment: I meant that you should not swap the margins in the first place, the outer margin should be larger. My point was that if you feared that too much of the page would disappear in the binding, then you should increase the binding correction to account for that.

Comment: VtC, the default is placing number and marginpar outside, as @TorbjørnT. says, why reversing it and then fixing it back? BCOR would be the road to go, but with this lack of information, no chance of giving a reliable answer.