# How to create a page number with a bar like on cleanthesis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-numbering, cleanthesis

I want a page number together with this bar like at the picture. I want it for all even page numbers on the left side and odd page numbers on the right side. I have the style idea from clean thesis, but I would prefer a more slim solution.

[image: page-number]

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145930/for-classicthesis-mirroring-format-of-chapter-numbers-and-graffito ;-)